# Sending Scheduled Emails with reports in Microsoft Dynamics GP

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

Is there  a way to schedule emails that attach a  SSIS web report or Smartlist report or excel report and send it automatically at a specified time within Microsoft Dynamics GP 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to send report automatically at a specified time within Microsoft Dynamics GP 2013. You can schedule reports in SSRS.